# What do spheres above dragons mean?

Tags: dragonvale

I have high level dragons above which there's a sphere, but recently I got one (an ice dragon) that had a sphere already at level one.

What do the spheres do, and why did one of them have one from the start?

Answer (score 2):

Spheres are a way of marking high level dragons in Dragonvale. They change to a crown when the dragon is level 20.

Epic dragons have a maximum level limit of 15. Epic dragons that have been raised above level 10 get a star above their head instead of a crown or a sphere.

Answer (score 0):

The Spheres are basically just a way of signifying the level of your dragon. If you get a dragon to level 10 a sphere pops up on top of their head. Even if you put the dragon into the fountain of youth, it will still have the sphere above its head.